# How to "hack" a C# file from a package to modify it according to my needs?

Tags: c#, class, nuget, abstract-class, package

I need to modify a C# file from a package I installed with NuGet to add some specificic functionnalities for my project.

I have the source code of the (abstract) class I want to modify ([see here](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap/blob/Branches/1.0/SharpMap/Rendering/Thematics/GradientTheme.cs)).

What is the correct way of importing the class in my VS2015 solution so that it will overwrite or take priority over the complete NuGet package already installed in my project ?

Comment: Do you have other nuget packages that depends on it?

Comment: Instead of modifying the class from the package, can you create a derived class that adds the functionality you need?

Answer (score 2):

In the source code file you referred to, it states that:

> This file is part of SharpMap.  SharpMap is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

That means you can download the source code, edit it, and maintain your new branch.  This is the easy way.

Of course you could try reverse-engineering the binaries, which would be counter-productive.  Or you can hope that the abstract class sits in its own DLL, then generate a new DLL to replace the original file.  Then run the app and cross your fingers.

I'd go the easy route.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the class manually adding source code of the class, something like this:

```
    namespace TheNUGETLibraryDll
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public virtual void MethodToChange()
        { }
    }
}

namespace YourProject
{
    public class DerivedClass : SomeClass
    {
        public override void MethodToChange()
        { }
    }
}
```